# VB.NET How to hide an inputbox in the taskbar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inputbox

I know there is a way to prevent the form to show in the taskbar. The problem is I don't know how to hide an InputBox in the taskbar, so the InputBox window shows but nothing is shown in the taskbar.

```
Dim newFileName As String = InputBox("Write the name of the new file.")
```

I have tried with `InputBox.ShowInTaskbar = False`, but obviously it isn't working.

How do I should solve this problem?
I am using VB.Net 2013

Comment: The InputBox shows up in the task bar?  Nobody knows that because nobody has used the InputBox since 1995.  Just create your own form with the proper settings.

Comment: :( i use the Input box! I have considered creating a form instead, i will now! Learning every day.

Comment: @Pete InputBox is fine when you want to get a simple string input from the user. The only thing is, it has some limitations, like the one in the question, for example. Not being able to tell whether the user canceled it or provided an empty string is also a big one. Therefore, it's almost always better to use a custom form instead.

Comment: In order to add controls to the taskbar, like a TEXTBOX (not INPUTBOX) where you want the user to enter text that you will do something with, you would add a RIBBON and then add the textbox into the ribbon. You cannot directly add controls to taskbar you can add ribbons though.